# How do I show a HTTP stream in a Vue.js app

Tags: node.js, vue.js, stream

I have a nodejs app that provides a HTTP stream via an endpoint, let's say /api/logs/{id}. Now, I have a frontend web app using Vue.js, and I want to consume that stream endpoint. How do I do that easiest?

The stream is an "endless" http stream.

Bonus: How can I combine multiple of this stream into one view?

Code in the nodejs app, to bring the stream out. The stream itself comes from dockerode.

```
exports.read_containerlogs = function (req, res) {
var container = docker.getContainer(req.params.containerid);

container.attach({stream: true, stdout: true, stderr: true}, function (err, stream) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' })
    stream.pipe(res);
});
```

};

Comment: What does the stream look like? What is the content-type of the response?

Comment: @AnkitKante Sorry, yeah. I edited the above post to include the code. It's basically json that comes out, byt CT is text/html right now. The format doesn't matter that much. The browser interprets it as json anyways now (FF at least).

Answer (score 0):

I followed this document to handle streams on the frontend: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams

```
fetch('/apiURL')
.then(response=> {
   const reader = reader.body.getReader()
   let data = []
   return reader.read().then(read = (result)=>{
     if(result.done){
       return data
     }

     data.push(result.value)
     return reader.read().then(read)
   })
})
.then(data => {
   // Do whatever you want with your data
})
```